# Substituting 2-row with DME - Extract Torpedo Clone recipe

Tags: all-grain, extract-brewing, clone-recipe

I really want to make an extract SN Torpedo Clone. During my hunt for recipes, this one in my opinion sounds great and I would really like to try it.

Recipe OP [here](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13902&start=32)

```
O.G. 1.076 (actual)
F.G. 1.016 (est)
ABV 7.0 (est)
IBU 82.7 (Tinseth, est)
SRM 8.8 (est)

23 lbs Great Western 2-row
2 lbs Cara-Pils Dextrine
1.5 lbs Crystal 60

70g Magnum 10.5% 90 minutes
28.3g Crystal 3.3% 90 minutes

50g Magnum 30 minutes

50g Magnum 10 minutes
100g Crystal 10 minutes

85g Crystal DRY 7 days
57g Magnum DRY 7 days
28g Citra DRY 7 days

Mash at 150 F
Mash Efficiency 80%

Yeast: White Labs WLP-001
```

I know to convert all-grain recipes to extract, you multiply the grain amount by .75 for LME and .6 for DME. Doing that for this recipe only gives about 3.9 kg for LME (in place of the 2-row).

Reading another post closer to the start of that thread, the creator of the recipe says:

> I'm gonna guess you could sub light DME for the pale 2-row and steep
>   the carapils and Crystal 40. Try running it through Promash and tweak
>   the DME until you hit 1.074. I'm kind of a noob, so I'd wait for
>   another opinion.
>
> Another thing, I might need to tweak the hops, so let me get a judges
>   opinion of it before you make it. I'll post that info soon as I can.
>
> Charlie

Does anybody know if simply throwing the recipe into a calculator (I've been using brewers friend recently) and tweaking the DME until it hits 1.076 is a good idea?

**Update**

How does this sound for a 22ltr batch: (All estimates are brewersfriend calulations)

```
O.G. 1.075 (est)
F.G. 1.021 (est)
ABV 7.12   (est)
IBU 74.39 (Tinseth, est)
SRM 11.01 (est)

BU/GU ratio: 0.99

4.5  KG Light DME          - 79.8%
0.65 KG Cara-Pils Dextrine - 11.5%
0.49 KG Crystal 60         -  8.7% 

35g Magnum               10.7% 90 minutes
14g Hallertau Mittelfruh 3.0%  90 minutes

25g Magnum                     30 minutes

25g Magnum                     10 minutes
50g Hallertau Mittelfruh       10 minutes 

42.5g Hallertau Mittelfruh DRY 7 days
28g   Magnum               DRY 7 days
14g   Citra                DRY 7 days

Yeast: 1.5 x 11.5g US-05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to preserve the ratio of 2-row to Crystal 60L.

Here is one simplified way to do the math.  2-Row has an average, theoretical extract yield of 1.036 specific gravity -- if you take the last two digits (36), you can express this as 36 gravity points per pound of grain per gallon of wort (PPG) at 100% efficiency.  The recipe assumes a mash efficiency of 80%, so you would only yield 36 PPG * 80% = 28.8 PPG.  DME has a PPG of 44.  How much DME do you need to replace one pound of 2-Row in this recipe? --> 28.8/44 = 0.65 lbs.  So you can replace 23 lbs. of 2-Row with 15 lbs of DME.

That being said, theoretical yield and actual extract yield from 2-Row are two different things.  While maltsters are very diligent and good about consistency in product despite inconsistency in raw barley, each batch of malt is different, but I doubt your LHBS has the malt spec sheet for the grain they have in bins out front.  Also, whether the recipe designer ever actually achieved 80% mash efficiency is doubtful.

DME is different in that it is a technically "perfected" product that gets you 44 PPG every time.

Ultimately, I think that the most important thing on brew day is to hit the OG while maintaining the ratio of fermentables. So I would start with the above numbers and then play with ALL of the fermentables to maintain the ratio and get to 1.076 OG. I think Brewer's Friend allows you to do that.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense actually, and how about the CaraPils? Should that also be increased proportionally to the DME?

Comment: Well, you can start by checking grain reference charts to help you with the math: [example one](http://www.beersmith.com/Grains/Grains/GrainList.htm), [example two](http://www.onebeer.net/grainchart.html). Carapils/Dextrin malt is used to add body, and while it will add to the gravity, it does not contribute much to fermentable sugar, giving you mostly unfermentable dextrins. I thought it had to be mashed, so I was surprised to see it does not in the grain reference. That being said, most extract brewers use maltodextrose, and you may wish to similarly convert the Carapils to maltodextrose.

Comment: To continue, if you you do not convert the Carapils, then you should try to keep the same ratio. Your updated recipe above seems reasonable.

Comment: Actually one more thing! I have Maltodextrin, would there be a good argument to use that instead of the Carapils? And how much ?

Comment: I know at least one very experienced, all-grain homebrewer who prefers to use matodextrin over dextrin malt/Carapils. I am leaning to the same conclusion. The cool thing about maltodextrin is that you can add it at any stage of the process, so the best time to add it may be in the bottling bucket, when you have tasted the finished, pre-carbonated beer (same idea if you are kegging).  As far as how much maltodextrin, here are a couple answers on that point: [post 1](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/11271/3950), [post 2](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/7986/3950).

Answer (score 0):

i have created the recipe for you using captainbrew.com. You can view it [here](http://www.captainbrew.com/view-recipe/104). You can clone the recipe and substitute Pale 2 row with DME, trying to keep the percentages.